Express js route named 'search' having weird behavior
This should work properly as the coide is correct.
the output should be - json on my browser window when the write the adress and load.
But i am seeing Searching for undefined written on my browser window.
And in the console
Server running on port 3000
Body:
{}
Query:
undefined
What the heck!!! I never implemented this. MY output is json always even if it fails in code.

Bckend code part

// app is express()
app.get('/search/',
    query('q').trim().notEmpty(),
    (req, res)=>{
        const queryParam = req.query.q;
        console.log(`Query parameter: ${queryParam}`);
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.send(errors);
        }
        const data = matchedData(req);
        res.send(data);   
    }
);


browser adress bar adress i used

http://localhost:3000/search/?q=abc

I tried changing the word 'search'. We can use anything there inplace of search where i used it. even searc - just removing a h - gives us desired result.
So the problem is in the word search as route.!!!
Why so? PLease explain.
Its killing me inside as it should not a problem by any chance.

I have tried reproduce your code but it's working. Can you check this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/express-playground-forked-87x5wn ?

Try turning off ALL your browser extensions
